# To say "my brother and sister," do I use мои because it's two of them or one each of моя and мой?

Tags: множественное-число, притяжательные-местоимения

I'm studying Russian from a grammar for Italians.

Here's one sentence from an exercise, with slots to insert possessives:

> Это моя семья. Вот ___ папа и ___ мама, а это ___ брат и сестра.

I'm pretty sure I have to insert мой and моя in the first two slots, but what about the third? Should I put мои there?

---

In Italian I would most likely repeat the adjective, hence going for what would literally be translated as мой брат и моя сестра.

Answer (score 10):

> Should I put мои there?

Yes, you should, and you got the other pronouns right as well.

> In Italian I would most likely repeat the adjective, hence going for what would literally be translated as мой брат и моя сестра.

You can do that in Russian as well (as you can see with the "mom and dad" example).

This excerpt is perfectly fine and grammatical, but a *very slightly* more idiomatic way of putting it would be *мои брат с сестрой*, literally "my brother with sister", or *i miei fratello con sorella*. This construct is used for things that usually go together in enumerations. It's not unlike the construct with *-que* (versus *et*) in Latin.

Enumerations that don't list closely related objects usually use the conjunction *а*, in which case you do need to duplicate the pronouns.

If you were being shown around your new workplace, the person giving you the tour would probably say: *это твой начальник, это твоё рабочее место, а это твоя зарплата*: "this is your boss, this is your desk and this is your salary". Putting it as **это твои начальник, рабочее место и зарплата* or **это твои начальник с рабочим местом и зарплатой* would sound a little bit weird because all these things belong to different domains.

Answer (score 4):

По-простому - можно поставить *мои*. НО!(если нужно правило, то можно читать самый конец)

Но это не совсем корректно, из-за нескольких сложных моментов, начиная с того, что так практически не говорят, и кончая тем, что можно написать и "**мой брат и сестра**" - что **тоже не будет ошибкой**, и скорее наоборот, будет вернее.

На текстовом ресурсе Нацкорпус упоминаний "мои брат с сестрой" - 0. По отношению к родственникам, мама - это моя мама в 99%, папа - это мой папа, и скорее скажут - это не мой папа, чем это мой папа. Бывает, уточняют, но уточнение не обязательно, тем более(!), что уже есть фраза: *Это ***моя*** семья*.

Употреблений "мои брат и сестра" - всего 3. Это очень мало, 1980 года, и два употребления 2000+ года, то есть это нехарактерно для классического русского языка.

Хотя если вы так скажете - то вас поймут, но странное звучание будет.

Ну ладно, чтобы не быть голословным, далее, "**мои** отец и мать":

> Ведь я родилась здесь, здесь жили **мои** отец и мать, мой дед, я люблю
> этот дом, без вишневого сада я не понимаю своей жизни, и если уж так
> нужно продавать, то продавайте и меня вместе с садом... Чехов. Классика.

Однако, тут "отец и мать"~родители - то есть это целостное по смыслу выражение, идиоматическое. Но тут еще есть "жили". И еще, Чехов склонен к психологизму в речи своих героев, то есть это звучит как акцент и этих акцентов много.

Однако, Толстой 19 век, не меньшая классика:

> Он сказал: " Есть, господин Мауер... "— " **Мой** отец и мать, — я
> сказал, — восемь лет **не видали** меня и не знают, жив ли я, или
> **кости мои** давно лежат в сырой земле. (и еще кости мои, а не мои кости(!))

Лесков, 19 век:

> К обеду приехали из Оптухи **мой** отец и мать: братья в парадной же
> кинулись друг другу на шею и от радости заплакали, жена дяди со всеми
> повидалась, сдержанно наблюдая тон и приличие.

Также могут быть употребления наоборот:

> Пусть будут браниться отец **мой** и мать, Ты свистни, — тебя не заставлю
> я ждать!.. Чуковский, 1970 год.
>
> Брат **мой** и сестра до того были испуганы звуком оружия. Романовский.

> Сестра **моя** и брат, оба меня моложе, остались в Симбирской губернии. Аксаков.

И даже так:

> — Твои советники правы, **отец и брат мой**: держать этакую птицу в клетке — все равно, что разложить костер на гумне в день умолота. Желябовский.

> До окончания войны тетка Надежда Петровна жила при отце, до той поры, пока **отец и мать моя** пригласили ее жить с нами; это, кажется, было незадолго до моего рождения. М. Ф. Каменская.

И даже так:

> **Отец и мать мои** были уже типичными петербуржцами. Лихачев 1995 год (академик и литературовед.)

То есть как упражнение для употребления мой/моя/мои - можно, но(!), так не говорят, так как **достаточно употребления один раз** - **мой** или **моя**. Ну а если в предыдущем предложении уже было "*моя семья*", то дальнейшее перечисление мой/моя выглядит как речевое излишество - ошибка.

И текст должен выглядеть как:

*Это моя семья: вот папа, мама, брат и сестра.*

И я склоняюсь к "**мой брат и сестра**", перед первым единичным существительным.

> «Какая чудная страна Финляндия!» — думал я, убедившись, что **и моё
> пальто, и шляпа, и зонт** также уже успели прикоснуться к какому-то
> мироточивому предмету, и на них блестели янтарные капли сосновой
> смолы. В. В. Брусянин.

*Это моя семья: **мой** папа, мама, брат и сестра.* (больше одного повтора явно перебор)

Либо как Лихачёв **мои**, но в самый конец.

*Это моя семья: папа, мама, брат и сестра **мои**.*

И, переходя уже к закономерности, то употребление местоимений при перечислении выглядит так([пример-ссылка](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/434198/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%95%D0%B4-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BD-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE)):

> *Вариант с "ваш**и**" грамматически верен, но **звучит несколько формально** и потому сухо*

> Пусть **Ваша** целеустремленность, **Ваш** профессионализм, **Ваша** творческая энергия послужат осуществлению всех благих замыслов и начинаний...

**То есть это ближе к тому варианту, к которому вы склонялись.**

И есть еще [такое обсуждение](https://otvet.mail.ru/question/170136771) с другого ресурса:

> Вопрос по грамматике русского языка: местоимение и дальнейшее перечисление
> Какое число принимает местоимение перед перечислением дальнейших слов? Например:
> Через **СВОИ** осознание, познание и развитие он пришёл к.. .    Или "через **СВОЁ** осознание, познание... "
> Пример 2: "он так любил **ЭТО** море, солнце, канапе, пляж" или "он так любил **ЭТИ** море, солнце, канапе, пляж.(вопрос)

> **во множественном числе даже не звучит**. надо использовать единственное число. Через **своё осознание**, познание и развитие... Он так любил **это море**, солнце, канапе, пляж... (ответ)

И [**вот еще ответ**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/448018/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) мне нравится, и он не такой длинный как этот мой!)

А Римма Михайловна шарит за русский, так что:

**Так как речь идет об одном человеке (о его восприятии), то употребление одного первого местоимения/прилагательного в единственном числе достаточно: мой отец, мать, брат и сестра.**

И это работает как для согласования местоимений, так и для согласования прилагательных:

> **Чей** тогда взгляд и улыбка будут освещать мне путь? Дикий гусь и утка
> прилетели первыми (Тургенев); необыкновенн**ый** шум и говор (Пушкин).

А "любим**ый** отец, любим**ая** матушка" звучит намного лучше, чем "любим**ые** отец и мать".

**Мои** же, я бы употребил, по отношению к предметам или объектам, которыми **владею или управляю**: это *мои* двор и дом / или даже / это *мои*: двор и дом. Но если это дом и двор к которым **я отношусь**, где проживаю, я бы сказал: это *мой* двор и дом / или / это мой дом и мой двор. Поэтому "мой отец и мать", либо "отец и мать мои" - с миграцией *мои* в конец.

Касательно прилагательных, если речь идет о предикате качества, то можно поставить множественное число: это (именно) чёрные шляпа и пиджак / или даже/ это чёрные: брюки и пиджак(если писать, а не говорить). А если без акцента, то: это чёрный пиджак и шляпа тоже чёрная. Как-нибудь так, два раза употребив цвет, отдельно, для каждой вещи при перечислении.

Спасибо, за очень интересный вопрос!

Comment: Для меня "мои брат и сестра" звучит стопроцентно идиоматично. Ничего странного  в звучании не нахожу.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh в примере, кстати, это.. брат и сестра, а не эти.. брат и сестра. А в английском было бы these - эти/те. Это не прямо ошибка, но *мои* звучит как формальное перечисление, не душевно звучит, с легким оттенком эгоизма. Русский язык очень хитрый в выборе слов и формах согласования, небольшое изменение может дать иную интонацию, потому что меняется акцент на определенном слове. Мои - выпячивается сильнее, чем мой. Да, можно говорить и так и так, но уже по выбору слов можно говорить о характере человека, русский язык очень связан с *речью*, потому он живой, а не формальный.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh мой/моя - это имеющий отношение ко мне в равной степени, как и я отношусь к тому, а моё/мои - принадлежащие мне, то чем я владею. Возможно, из-за ты и вы. Ну и смещение мои в конец, дает ослабление управления, владения.

Comment: @άνθρωπος, wow! An answer completely in russian *_* I don't understand much of it now, but I think I'll learn a lot just by setting understanding it as my own goal. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Enlico Your goal is really great, welcome! Грамоте учиться всегда пригодится.(пословица)

Comment: @Enlico Now you don't have to read War and Peace! 